# How to get some value from the sql database based on certain criteria

Tags: sql

[Suppose I have given such a table in sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrECy.png)
According to Gmail (which I have given in advance) I want to get the Username value.
For example, if "Gmail" would be "Gela1@gmail.com" I should get string - "Gela gela".
if "Gmail" would be "mamuka@gmail.com" I should get string - "Mamuka snaia".
How to do this?

Comment: but, I want to store it in a string variable, in visual studio

Comment: How do you get `"Mamuka snaia"` from `"mamuka@gmail.com"`? Are there other table fields we don't know about? What language (C#, VB, etc.) are you using, and which SQL Engine (Sql Server, MySql, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make an SQL query like:

```
SELECT Username from tableName where Gmail = 'Gela1@gmail.com'
```

Replace tableName with your table name.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp

Comment: w3*ools... SQL has single quotes for string literals. Double quotes are for delimited identifiers, e.g. column names with odd characters.

Comment: It looks like they also want a substring of the result (e.g. `"Gela"` from `"Gela1@gmail.com"`).